# Type 'Notification.Name' (aka 'NSNotification.Name') has no member 'UIApplication'

Tags: swift, notificationcenter

First it said that

> 'UIApplicationDidEnterBackground' has been renamed to
>   'UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification'

and when I dot it,it said

> Type 'Notification.Name' (aka 'NSNotification.Name') has no member
>   'UIApplication'

```
func listenForBackgroundNotification() {
    observer = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground, object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) { [weak self] _ in
        if let weakSelf = self {
            if weakSelf.presentedViewController != nil {
                weakSelf.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            weakSelf.descriptionTextView.resignFirstResponder()

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, still have the same error

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Change

```
forName: Notification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground
```

to

```
forName: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification
```

Comment: it says: 'didEnterBackgroundNotification' has been renamed to 'NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground'

Answer (score 5):

Error with Type 'NSNotification' has no member 'UIApplication' in swift4.2

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(handleNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground, object: nil)
```

Need to Change accordingly

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(handleNotification), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
```

Answer (score 4):

Xcode 11 , swift 5

```
UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification
```

Comment: You forgot `import UIKit`

Answer (score 3):

If `UIApplicaiton.didEnterBackgroundNotificaiton` isn't working, try just `.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground` instead.

Answer (score 2):

**Xcode 11.4.1, Swift 5**

Had the exact same issue. My problem was I didn't import UIKit in my custom class

```
import UIKit
```

Then I was able to  implement the following:

```
name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification
```